# graph dataset on canvas

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, observablecollection, mousemove

observablecollection1 + observablecollection2  <---databinding---> canvas :

is there a canvas that allows move shapes and having databiding whith an observablecollection.

exemple :
you have an ObservableCollection BaseCamp (camp,x,y,otherproperity) and these camps are connected  via ObservableCollection roads (camp1,camp2,colors).
i want to see my data on a canvas and move a camp, add a road and so on.

its , i think a classical use but i don't see such a canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the animation yourself.

Basically, you call a function every X seconds that :

- clear the canvas
- draw your shapes with the properties of your *BaseCamp*

More information at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-linear-motion-animation/

note that the correct way to set a timeout is

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
function(callback){
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
};
```

})();